# Tree with countable height and exactly $\aleph_1$-many maximal branches

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

*Definition* A tree means a set-theoretic tree, that is a poset $(T,<)$ so that for each $x\in T$, the set $\{y\in T|y<x\}$ is well-ordered.

**Question** Assume CH fails and let $\aleph_1\le\kappa< 2^{\aleph_0}$. Is it possible that a tree of countable height and countable levels has **exactly** $\kappa$ many maximal branches through the tree?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, and this is because every uncountable closed set of reals contains a perfect set. This is how Cantor proved that the continuum hypothesis holds for closed sets.

The easiest way to prove it is by using the [Cantor-Bendixson analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)#Cantor.E2.80.93Bendixson_rank): if you iteratively cast out isolated points from your closed set, then in countably many steps you'll arrive at a perfect set. So every closed set is the union of a countable set and a perfect set. Every perfect set has size continuum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you assuming that the height of the tree equals $\omega$?

Comment: If it has some other countable height, just restrict to a cofinal $\omega$-sequence, and the same argument applies. The set of branches will be isomorphic to a closed set in Baire space $\omega^\omega$.

Comment: Maybe the problem is more interesting in the case of a tree with height $\lambda>\aleph_0$ and levels of size $\lambda$ and $\lambda^+\le\kappa<2^\lambda$.

Comment: That is a very interesting question, about which I have to think more. I think this might be known. I'd encourage you to ask as a separate question.

Comment: Ok. I will post it separately.

Comment: Another "easy way"  to get the perfect kernel of an uncountable closed set is to (instead of "iteratively cast out the isolated points') just take the set of condensation points,

Comment: These are called "Jech-Kunen" trees, or I would imagine $\lambda$-Jech Kunen trees ($\lambda=\omega_1$ is the usual case). Renling Jin has a few papers about these. One can have Jech-Kunen trees but no Kurepa trees, as well as other interesting situations.